# .Logo images are not showing in transactional emails magento2

Tags: magento2, product, logo

I can see the logo image and product images in the email logs backend. But in emails, the logo image and product images are not displayed.

Comment: Please provide more details. What is the version of magento? Where do you see your emails and what do you see in the source of the email etc...

Comment: Magento ver 2.4.1 p1. 
I can't see logo and productimages in the  emails,while placing order, new shipment created, whislist shared etc.. .

Comment: Can you please confirm did you upload the logo image in Content -> Design -> Configuration -> {Select your current theme} -> Transactional Emails -> Logo Image.

Comment: Yes, I already uploaded the logoimage in Content -> Design -> Configuration -> {Select your current theme} -> Transactional Emails -> Logo Image

Comment: The issue is fixed. It is an authentication issue

Comment: @shihab maybe place the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please Go to admin panel and upload the logo image at

> Content -> Design -> Configuration -> {Select your current theme} ->
> Transactional Emails -> Logo Image

Comment: Uploaded but still it is not displaying. It displays logo alt in the mail.

Comment: Make sure proper permission for logo image.